# Restart the numbering of the reference labels in the appendix body in overleaf

Tags: reference, latex, label, bibliography, overleaf

I have created a supplementary section in my journal manuscript using the following script:

```
\appendix
%%%
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{S}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{S\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%%%
\begin{center}
\section*{Supplementary Material}
\end{center}
%%%
\subsection{Sub-heading1}
```

A separate bibliography also has been generated for the appendix using the multibib package as follows:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{supp}{Supplementary References}
```

and declaring

```
%% Loading supplementary bibliography style file
\bibliographystylesupp{unsrt}
% Loading supplementary bibliography database
\bibliographysupp{cas-sc-template-refs.bib}

\end{document}
```

resulting in a reference section that looks like this:
[Supplmentary References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G58L.png)

However, the reference labels in the body text does not change:

> S.2. Discussion
> S.2.1. Subheading2
> The role of the structural of squares and the circles is clearly seen in the
> interdependence of property on the values of energy and density as
> shown in Figures S.4a and S.4b. There is a clear clustering of data
> points based on the primary property as viewed against its dependence
> on secondary property in Figures S.4c. The high-value  compositions
> are observed to be all apples and the medium value ones are observed
> to be oranges. The values thus predicted placed most of them in the
> low– and medium–value range [66].

The reference numbers are still from the main document's bibliography.

I have tried the `\DeclareOption{resetlabels}{\continuouslabelsfalse} option` in the multibib package documentation given in http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf but to no avail.

Is there any way to renumber these reference labels as well?

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre]